# Closer zoom than 400% in Crystal Reports for Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I've managed to get Visual Studio to zoom in to 400% on the Crystal Reports designer, but it's not enough.

I can't vertically align text within a box, and so I'm needing to use box objects for my borders. I can't use the auto-sizing and auto-alignment tools with box objects.

Thus, I am forced to perform manual alignment on all of my border elements. Unfortunately, even though I can get to a respectable "400%" zoom, it's obviously not enough, as I'm getting 1- and 2-"printer pixel" misalignments in the final printouts (sorry, I'm sure there's a real term for it, but I don't know it).

Is it possible to get closer (more accurate) than this? Is there some method to accurately specify the proper size and positioning of boxes? Is there some way to use the alignment and sizing tools on boxes?

Any of these would be helpful.

Comment: Being off by two pixels is a mis-alignment of 0.0033", 0.085 mm.  Are you using a microscope?

Comment: @Hans, Frosty is talking about the width of the default border. I think.

Comment: @Hans Passant: I'm not using an exact measure, here. All I know is that there's a visible misalignment on the printout and that there is no visible misalignment on the form on the screen. I haven't used my handy-dandy electron microscope to measure the exact extent of the misalignment. What I'm looking for is a way to auto-align/auto-size these elements as one would auto-size certain other elements, or even just to zoom in further in order to align them better by hand. PowerUser indicates that this is not possible, which is a shame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer:** No

**Long Answer:**  I use Crystal XI to generate PDF Reports and I know exactly what you're talking about.  You can snap the left & top edges of a border to the grid, but not the right or bottom edge, so you can't perfectly align everything.  Moreover, even if it looks fine in the Designer, the discrepancy shows up in the PDF.

My best suggestion is just to "work with it as best you can".